# Firebase rules: Create if collection id does not exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What I am trying to do is create a firebase rule that will allow create operations if an id does not exist in `allow create`. To be specific, I am using firestore, not the firebase real time db. I am really new to firebase, but have done some research before posting here. Most of the examples I see are around auth.

Consider the follow data structure. The name of the collection is called `flags`

```
US - //(This is the document ID. Not auto generated
  - country: United Stages
  - name: US
  - colors: [red, white, blue]
UK - 
  - country: United Kingdom
  - name: UK
  - colors: [red, white, blue]
```

What I am trying to do write a rule, IF `name` in the posted data does not match an existing document ID. The reason why I opted to set my own document ID is because of this [article](https://bigcodenerd.org/enforce-cloud-firestore-unique-field-values/)

My current rule is:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read: if isLoggedIn();
    allow create: if ! exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/flags/$(inComing().name))

    // functions
    function isLoggedIn() {
        return request.auth != null
    }

    function inComing() {
        return request.resource.data
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try posting some data with a non existent document id, I am getting an access denied error. I am logged into the app so I know it is not failing on the first part of the rule.

In summary, my questions are:

- How can i check if a document ID exists based on the posted datas `name` key?

So what i am try is `allow create: if ! exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/flags/$(inComing().name))`. In the simulator, I am using `create`, and setting the path to `flags/US`. The payload is:

```
{"__name__":"/databases/(default)/documents/flags/US","id":"US","data":{"name":"US"}}
```

If I run the simulator, i get access denied which is expected. But if i change the path to `flags/CA` or change the payload to `{"name":"CA"}`, which does not exist, I am getting getting an access denied.